# Can not use eval in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eval

This is my code :

```
 collection = cubsfantony 848 visa/mastercard, money order/cashiers checks

 temp = regexprep(collection,' ',''',''')
```

%return

```
temp = cubsfantony','848','visa/mastercard,','money','order/cashiers','checks'  % why?

eval(['words = {''',temp,'''};']);
```

And Matlab return as follows:

```
 Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: ??? What Matlab expression is `={''temp''};`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri a very unexpected MATLAB expression apparently. No wonder MATLAB does not agree, it comes as a surprise for me as well

Comment: What are you trying to do, and why are you using `eval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `eval` at all... please don't use it.  It's considered bad practice.  However, it is my understanding that you want to split up all strings that are separated by spaces and place them into a separate cell array.  You can easily do that with [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) and use the space character as the splitting delimiter character:

```
collection = 'cubsfantony 848 visa/mastercard, money order/cashiers checks';
out = strsplit(collection, ' ');
```

We get:

```
>> out = strsplit(collection, ' ')

out = 

  Columns 1 through 4

    'cubsfantony'    '848'    'visa/mastercard,'    'money'

  Columns 5 through 6

    'order/cashiers'    'checks'
```